# when i want to run my code on docker container i get a path error

Tags: python, docker, data-analysis

I have a python code. The code checks the folder A every 15 seconds and if there is a csv file there, process it and generates an html report with the same name. I want to run my code on a docker container. The code is working without docker. However, when i want to run my code on docker container i get a path error.
( [my dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRW3y.png)  )

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fseOY.png)

These are lines about errors :

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP9JV.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EViWT.png)

Comment: Unclear. Attach your Dockerfile and your code structure

Comment: You can try either copy your csv files with command COPY in Dockerfile or mount volumes with flag -v of command 'docker run'
But you must use absolute path for your container in python script

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the code or error messages in your question.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including the actual code and error messages; directly in the question and not behind links, as plain text and not as images?

Answer (score 0):

A docker container cannot access the host file system. You need to mount your folder into the container.

```
docker run docker-hw -v "C:\\path\\host:/path/inside/container"
```

Then use "/path/inside/container" for the python script.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to load a local file on your host machine through the script which is running in the docket instance. use the `cp` command in your yaml file to copy that file to the docket file system, and then just reference it from there